# Can i target parent div based on table inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where i want to target parent `div` which has table inside.

Parent `div` has dynamic generated class which make it hard for me to target but the `table` inside `div` has fixed class name `tablepress` as show in example below

```
<div class="elementor-125">
<table class="tablepress">
......
</table>
</div>

<div class="elementor-126">
<table class="tablepress">
......
</table>
</div>
<div class="elementor-127">
<table class="tablepress">
......
</table>
</div>
```

Is there a ways using CSS only so that i can target parent `div` of table using class `tablepress`

I have been looking but didnt find a working example as lot of forum say it is not supported yet and other way round is possible is i know but i want to target parent div based on child class

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: No, there is no parent selector in CSS. You need to use Javascript/jQuery to achieve that.

Comment: I was afriad of it, unfortunately i cant use jQuery/JS. I thought it may have been added as this has been in wish-list of developers for several years now.